# Using Linq to get a list of Ids as a List(Of String) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have an IList(Of Customer) and with Linq I am trying to add each customerId to a list of type string.

Here is what I thought would work but it does not:

```
Dim s As List(Of String) = (From c In customers Select c.Id).ToList(Of String)
```

Comment: The type of Id is integer, but I need them in a list of type String

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't implicitly convert types just by using a different generic parameter for `ToList`.  You have to convert either using a cast or a projection.

Just use `ToString` to project as a string:

```
Dim s As List(Of String) = (From c In customers Select (c.Id.ToString())).ToList()
```

Comment: When compiling it I get: Range variable name cannot match the name of a member of the 'Object' class and when I double click it, it takes me to .ToString()

Comment: Had to wrap c.Id.ToString() in parenthesis. VB.NET for the win

Comment: I forgot VB requires `ToString()` to be in parentheses or it will try to create a property called `ToString`.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use selet method of Linq to select ids from the list

Dim ids As List(Of String)  = customers.[Select](Function(x) x.id.ToString()).ToList()